# Eject from Expo and come back again to it

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development

I am working on a mobile application in `Expo` and after I reached to 30 percent of progress in my project, I realized that I can not use `Mapbox` libraries with `Expo`.
So My question is that, if I reject from `Expo` and write my `Mapbox` related codes in `React Native`, after that can I come back again to `Expo` to develop the rest of the project in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eject your project with Expo kit. So you can work on native code and expo modules too.

Comment: So that means that all of my previous codes still will work ?

Comment: Yes. When you eject the project by expo kit, it will have the guide. Follow it and your code will work well. After that, you can use the native library and expo library too.

Answer (score 0):

`after that can I come back again to Expo to develop the rest of the project in that?`

No, you can't go back again to the expo is not reversible